# Node.js - core cluster module

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing

I am using the core cluster module in node v0.6.5. I have the following code:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var http = require('http');
var numWorkers = 3;

var count = 0;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (var i = 0; i < numWorkers; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }
} else {
  console.log('createServer called');
  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    count++;
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Count is: ' + count.toString());
  }).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
}
```

Everytime I hit the page, the count is incremented twice, e.g. 1,3,5,7... Why does it increment twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably another case where the browser is silently requesting `/favicon.ico`, thus making there 2 requests per page.

Comment: Gotcha. Another small doubt: the child workers share the global variables is it? Meaning - the child processes utilize the CPU cores right? But, they still have access to the global variable?

Comment: That I'm not familiar with enough to help you on, I just knew about the browser's silent request there. Sorry :(